How do I send multiple key/values in a Message for Handler?
Message msg = Message.obtain();
msg.obj = "first string value";
msg.setTarget(mClientMessenger);
msg.sendToTarget();

I would like msg.obj to hold two key/value pairs if possible.
Ex:
key1, "first string value"
key2, "second string value"
Then I would like to know how to receive them if possible.
Edit:
I tried..
public class KeyValues {
  key1;
  key2;
  KeyValues(String value1, String value2){
    this.key1 = value1;
    this.key2 = value2;
  }
}

Message msg = Message.obtain();
msg.obj = new KeyValues("first string", "second string");
msg.setTarget(mClientMessenger);
msg.sendToTarget();

In the client's message handler I tried..
MyService.KeyValues keyValues = (MyService.KeyValues) msg.obj

but it threw an exception for improper casting of "Message" object.

To pass multiple key-value pairs in a Message object in Android, you can use a Bundle. A Bundle is a collection of key-value pairs and can be easily put into a Message object
You can send message like below
    private void sendMessage() {
        // Create a new Bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key1", "first string value");
        bundle.putString("key2", "second string value");

        // Obtain a new Message object
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.setData(bundle); // Set the Bundle as the data of the Message
        msg.setTarget(mHandler);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

Receiving the messages
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            // Retrieve the Bundle from the Message
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

            // Extract the values from the Bundle
            String value1 = bundle.getString("key1");
            String value2 = bundle.getString("key2");

            // Use the values as needed
            Log.d("Handler", "Value1: " + value1 + ", Value2: " + value2);
        }


I was just trying this.  Was almost there.  Thanks for confirming!

Happy coding..!

It is complaining my mClientMessenger is a Messenger and not a Handler object.  Can I get the handler from the messenger somehow?

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
super.handleMessage(msg);
// Retrieve the Bundle from the Message
Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        // Extract the values from the Bundle
        String value1 = bundle.getString("key1");
        String value2 = bundle.getString("key2");

        // Use the values as needed
        Log.d("Handler", "Value1: " + value1 + ", Value2: " + value2);
    }
};


I wasn't able to edit my comment but what I did was msg.what = MSG_VALUES and mClientMessenger.send(msg).  I was able to send using the Messenger object.  Sorry, I'm not able to upvote yet either.
